# DependencyManagement in Transitive Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am looking for a thorough explanation or a definitive source on the following issue:

When artifact A has a dependency on artifact B, and artifact B has a dependencyManagement section, is this section also used to build the dependency graph?

If so, in which order are the evaluations of dependencyManagement in the dependency graph?

My impression (after first experiments) is that dependencyManagement is not (fully) included, but I wonder how e.g. versionless dependencies are handled.

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example of this?

Comment: I create a jar B that sets log4j to version 1.2.17 in dependencyManagement. B also really uses log4j transitively, but without dependencyManagement, the version would be 1.2.15. If I create another jar A that depends on B, do I inherit log4j 1.2.17 or do I inherit log4j 1.2.15? Another scenario: B has a versionless entry for log4j in the dependencies. Is the version of log4j then determined by B's dependencyManagement (when used by A)? This can get arbitrarily complicated if I have jars A -> B -> C -> D which all have dependencyManagement.